# Splitting order quantities by type and scoop

Tags: python, pandas

Have the following dataframes:

```
**ASK**
Date        Type    Scoop   Qty
-------------------------------
6-Oct-17    A       Single  80
10-Oct-17   B       Triple  90
9-Oct-17    D       Double  40
10-Oct-17   C       Double  20
10-Oct-17   B       Triple  90
9-Oct-17    A       Single  30

**ICECREAMTYPE**
Type    Scoop   Flavour1    Flavour2    Flavour3    Scoops/Tub  Proportion
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
A       Single  Strawberry                                  4       0.25
C       Double  Banana      Lemon                           2       0.25
B       Triple  Vanilla     Lemon       Mint                3       0.11
D       Double  Chocolate   Vanilla                         5       0.10
```

Based on proportion, looking for a python logic that helps to detemine how many Tubs of icecream to be ordered.

Output desired is:

```
**ORDERTUBS**
Date        Type    Scoop       Flavour     Qty
------------------------------------------------
6-Oct-17    A       Flavour1    Strawberry  20
10-Oct-17   B       Flavour1    Vanilla     10
10-Oct-17   B       Flavour2    Lemon       10
10-Oct-17   B       Flavour3    Mint        10
9-Oct-17    D       Flavour1    Chocolate   4
9-Oct-17    D       Flavour2    Vanilla     4
10-Oct-17   C       Flavour1    Banana      5
10-Oct-17   C       Flavour2    Lemon       5
10-Oct-17   B       Flavour1    Vanilla     10
10-Oct-17   B       Flavour2    Lemon       10
10-Oct-17   B       Flavour3    Mint        10
9-Oct-17    A       Flavour1    Strawberry  7.5
```

Thanks!

Comment: I assuming it is `pandas` related question

Comment: Nice! Yes, it is a pandas question. How did you manage to convert the text in the text to df and df1 dataframes? Was it done from the clipboard?

Comment: Yes, using `pd.read_clipboard()` also you can check my answer :)

Comment: Is there a way to convert the df = pd.readclipboard().drop(0) to display as an array/dictionary in jupyter? This would help resolve issue of two dataframes, which gets overwritten on one clipboard.

Comment: @Wen I think I got a way to do it using `df.to_dict('split')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want ? I break done the steps

```
import pandas as pd
Target=df.merge(df1.drop('Scoop',1),on='Type',how='left')
Target=Target.set_index(['Date','Type','Scoop','Qty','Scoops/Tub','Proportion']).stack().reset_index()
Target['Qty']=Target['Qty']*Target['Proportion']
Target.drop(['Scoops/Tub','Proportion','Scoop'],1).rename(columns={'level_6':'Scoop',0:'Flavour'})

Out[49]: 
         Date Type   Qty     Scoop     Flavour
0    6-Oct-17    A  20.0  Flavour1  Strawberry
1   10-Oct-17    B   9.9  Flavour1     Vanilla
2   10-Oct-17    B   9.9  Flavour2       Lemon
3   10-Oct-17    B   9.9  Flavour3        Mint
4    9-Oct-17    D   4.0  Flavour1   Chocolate
5    9-Oct-17    D   4.0  Flavour2     Vanilla
6   10-Oct-17    C   5.0  Flavour1      Banana
7   10-Oct-17    C   5.0  Flavour2       Lemon
8   10-Oct-17    B   9.9  Flavour1     Vanilla
9   10-Oct-17    B   9.9  Flavour2       Lemon
10  10-Oct-17    B   9.9  Flavour3        Mint
11   9-Oct-17    A   7.5  Flavour1  Strawberry
```

---

Data Input :

```
df
Out[50]: 
        Date Type   Scoop  Qty
0   6-Oct-17    A  Single   80
1  10-Oct-17    B  Triple   90
2   9-Oct-17    D  Double   40
3  10-Oct-17    C  Double   20
4  10-Oct-17    B  Triple   90
5   9-Oct-17    A  Single   30

df1
Out[51]: 
  Type   Scoop    Flavour1 Flavour2 Flavour3  Scoops/Tub  Proportion
0    A  Single  Strawberry      NaN      NaN           4        0.25
1    C  Double      Banana    Lemon      NaN           2        0.25
2    B  Triple     Vanilla    Lemon     Mint           3        0.11
3    D  Double   Chocolate  Vanilla      NaN           5        0.10
```

Comment: @piRSquared lol, when I saw key wordc `Dataframe` , it smell like a `pandas` question :)

Comment: Did you see my link in the comments though?  I love that answer!

Comment: @piRSquared I am look into it dude, I am addict to your answer ...even forget to upvote it ... :)